# How to make a pipe in PuTTY ssh?

Tags: locale, suse

I need help to make a pipe in PuTTY ssh conected to open suse.

The problem is that i don't know how to put this character "|" (I press AltGr + 1) but don't work in PuTTY.

The language of the keyboard is "Español (Argentina)".

I change the keyboard language for "Spanish (International Literacy)" and now its working.

Answer (score 2):

you can try ALT 0124 
digits from numeric keypad

Answer (score 1):

If it's a U.S. keyboard, it's <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>. This is the same on most international keyboards too, though some have <kbd>¦</kbd>, which I think will emit the same character.

It might help to know which language your keyboard layout is for.

Comment: I change the keyboard language for "Spanish (International Literacy)" and now its working. Thank you Marcelo for the inspiration!

Answer (score 0):

You can do so, without changing the keyboard layout, by going to "Change Settings", then "Keyboard", and at the bottom in "Enable Extra Features" uncheck "Control-Alt is different from AltGr". Now you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> to output a pipe.